# PHP Strange Floating Point Imprecision

Tags: php

if I try to print

```
echo ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);
```

output (http://codepad.org/m3mNNO77)

```
8
```

but if I try to print

```
echo (int)((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);
```

output (http://codepad.org/8OTCnlVG)

```
7
```

why two different results ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: Re-opening this question because, while we have seen floating point errors countless times, this is a particularly interesting edge case that is completely unrelated to the "duplicate".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you perform the `echo` without the `(int)` cast, it resulits in:

```
echo ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);
8
```

So what happens is that the floating point actually represents it as 7.99999....

When you perform an `(int)` cast, the default behavior is to take the integral part, so that's `7`. Although it is extremely close to `8`, it is not the behavior of a cast to round off.

The errors are due to the fact that floating point numbers are represented with a binary radix. Representing `0.8` correctly is thus **impossible**. Floating points round off the answers, and hope it doesn't bother that much. When you represent the floating point like `0.8`, the result is `0.80000...`

**Proof of concept** using the PHP interactive shell (`php -a`):

```
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > echo number_format(((0.1 + 0.7) * 10),20)."\n";
7.99999999999999911182
php > echo number_format(0.8,20);
0.80000000000000004441
```

Comment: thanks for your response! now understand this oddity.

Answer (score 3):

As you may be aware, floating point math is not exact due to restrictions in their representation.

`(0.1 + 0.7) * 10` works out to something like `7.99999999999...`.

When `echo`'d out, the number is converted to a string using *rounding*, which uses the php.ini `precision` setting (15 by default, I believe) to limit the number of decimal numbers. It happens that this rounding gives exactly `8`.

However, `(int)` casts the float to an integer instead, and this is done with truncation. It doesn't matter how close to the next integer up you are, it will *always* round down. This is why you get `7` here.